# Trouble with twitter integration on Java, Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create app with twitter integration (Twitter4j library). I created this code:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
.setOAuthConsumerKey("*")
.setOAuthConsumerSecret("*")
.setOAuthAccessToken("*")
.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*");
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

try {
    Status status=twitter.updateStatus("hello world!");
} catch (TwitterException e) {}
```

But this code work with developer's account only. I try to use cb.setUser() and cb.setPassword(), but it doesn't work. I need a activity with 2 edittext: 1 for login and 2 for password. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer [twitter](http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application) It is also helpful for me.